# Сортировка myQSL и выборка.

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в одной из ее колонок является типа int с числами, надо начать выборку с наибольшего числа по убыванию. Как составить mySQL запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT YourField
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY YourField DESC
```

Подучите немного SQL - подобные вопросы должно быть стыдно задавать